# Flattening an array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the folders in a json file as follows:

```json
[{ "name": "Knowledge Base",
    "files": [
    {
      "name": "Documents",
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "Quarterly Results"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Favourites",
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "Brawl Stars",
          "files": [
            {
              "name": "NS dying in 5 seconds"
            },
            {
              "name": "Josiah raping NS"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Coding",
          "files": [
            {
              "name": "Coding is so fun"
            },
            {
              "name": "I love svelte",
              "files": [
                {
                  "name": "REPL"
                },
                {
                  "name": "oh nooo"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Favourites 1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Favourites 2"
        },
        {
          "name": "Favourites 3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Knowledge Base 1"
    }
    ]
  }]
```

How do I flatten this array of objects such that I would get the desired output below such that, ignoring files and only caring about folders (which have files inside):

All possible routes that can be taken by going through all folders, ignoring files with no other files inside them.

Knowledge Base > Documents

Knowledge Base > Favourites > Brawl Stars

Knowledge Base > Favourites > Coding

Knowledge Base > Favourites > Coding > I love svelte

I figured out using a recursive function, but I dont know how to go from there.

Comment: Use your recursive solution to "descend" the tree, building up a path along the way and appending each new path to a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const rootFiles = [{"name":"Knowledge Base","files":[{"name":"Documents","files":[{"name":"Quarterly Results"}]},{"name":"Favourites","files":[{"name":"Brawl Stars","files":[{"name":"NS dying in 5 seconds"},{"name":"Josiah raping NS"}]},{"name":"Coding","files":[{"name":"Coding is so fun"},{"name":"I love svelte","files":[{"name":"REPL"},{"name":"oh nooo"}]}]},{"name":"Favourites 1"},{"name":"Favourites 2"},{"name":"Favourites 3"}]},{"name":"Knowledge Base 1"}]}]

function getDirectoryPaths(files) {
  return files.flatMap(({name, files: childFiles}) => childFiles ? [
    name,
    ...getDirectoryPaths(childFiles).map(childPath=>`${name}>${childPath}`)
  ] : [])
}

console.log(getDirectoryPaths(rootFiles))

// or, if you don't want the top-level directory listed:
console.log(getDirectoryPaths(rootFiles).slice(1))
```

Comment: Hi can you please elaborate on your code? Sorry I'm new and dont really understand it, especially the `??`

Comment: @Harry I removed the `??` operator, it was unnecessary. If you don't know what certain operators mean, like `...` or `?` or `, you can look them up here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators  What the code does is visit every item which has a files property, or if that property is missing, returns empty array. In other words, visit every directory. Then simply prepend the parent directory name to every directory returned through a recursive call to examine further down the file tree. Recursive code is a brain teaser - try using a debugger to step through

Comment: The new version also uses destructuring, to extract the name and files properties from each item https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 0):

In your recursive function just check if object has `files` property:

```js
const data = [{ "name": "Knowledge Base",
    "files": [
    {
      "name": "Documents",
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "Quarterly Results"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Favourites",
      "files": [
        {
          "name": "Brawl Stars",
          "files": [
            {
              "name": "NS dying in 5 seconds"
            },
            {
              "name": "Josiah raping NS"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Coding",
          "files": [
            {
              "name": "Coding is so fun"
            },
            {
              "name": "I love svelte",
              "files": [
                {
                  "name": "REPL"
                },
                {
                  "name": "oh nooo"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Favourites 1"
        },
        {
          "name": "Favourites 2"
        },
        {
          "name": "Favourites 3"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Knowledge Base 1"
    }
    ]
  }];
  
function flatten(obj, parent = "")
{
  parent += obj.name + ">"; //append current folder name
  let result = [];
  if (obj.files)
  {
    result = obj.files
      .filter(file => file.files) //only leave folders
      .map(file => parent + file.name);//add names
  }

  if (Array.isArray(obj.files))
    result = result.concat(...obj.files.map(folder => flatten(folder, parent))); //recursivly call flatten for next subfolder

  return result;
}


const dataFlat = data.reduce((a,b) => (a.push(...flatten(b)), a), []);

console.log(dataFlat);
```